# Relación uno a muchos Entity Framework c#

Tags: c#, windows-forms, entity-framework

estoy comenzando a utilizar este Framework. Tengo dos clases:

```
public class Pedido
    {
        public int PedidoId { get; set; }
        public int Estado { get; set; };
        public virtual ICollection<Producto> Productos { get; set; }
}

public class Producto
    {
        public int ProductoId { get; set; }
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
        public string Descripcion { get; set; }
        public string Tipo { get; set; }
        public float Precio { get; set; }
        public bool Cocina { get; set; }
        public byte[] Imagen { get; set; }

        public int PedidoId { get; set; }
        public virtual Pedido Pedido { get; set; }

    }
```

Lo que no entiendo muy bien es como manejarme a la hora de de almacenar Productos que no hagan referencia a ningun pedido, es decir, cuando son creados. Debo crear otra clase Productoque no este enlazada con Pedido?
Espero haberme explicado bien. Gracias

Comment: Hola, cuales son tus reglas de negocio? Porque ese modelo a mi entender es incorrecto ya que un producto puede estar asociado a muchos pedidos y a la vez un pedido suele tener muchos productos (esto ultimo puede llegar a ser opcinal dependiendo el negocio) Con este modelo estas limitando a que un mismo producto este en muchos pedidos.

Comment: Amigo en todo caso deberías replantear tu modelo puesto que alomejor necesitas una tabla intermedia ejemplo ProductoPedidos y tu relación sería many_to_many ya que un producto puede estar en varios pedidos y un pedido puede tener varios productos

Comment: Me sigue costando entender un poco la situacion, ejemplo: tengo un grid con todos los productos almacenados en la bd, estos productos serian como el "menu" y no estarian relacionados con ningun pedido. A ver si ahi me explique mejor. Como almaceno este "menu" de productos?

Comment: Los productos no deben tener ninguna relacion a un pedido. Quienes usan los productos son los pedidos. Las reglas que estan planteando estan mal por ese motivo. Si mostraras una lista de productos, solo listarias esa "tabla".